# PHP - how to extract this value from html?

Tags: php, parsing, xpath

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="12345678" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="someurl/?album=1&amp;gallery=15" />
```

I need to get id of `gallery` which in this case is `15`.

**How im trying to accomplish this:**

```
$html = <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="12345678" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="someurl/?album=1&amp;gallery=15" />";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $dom);
$galleryid = $xpath->query(//how to get gallery id?);
```

Comment: what have a you tried? and where have u tried this

Comment: Where you want that and how to post that data on server?

Comment: If this is posted in a form, you could use `$_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer']` to get the hidden-field, and then either use regex or a simple split to find the value you want.

Comment: Im accessing html page, which is already rendered. No submit action :)

Comment: `substr($url, strpos('gallery=', $url) + strlen('gallery='))` or something similar. use your brain.

Comment: @RhymeGuy if it's already rendered, then why is your question tagged `PHP`?

Comment: Because you can't extract anything using HTML.

Comment: Post updated. I just want to extract some part of html, for some reason. Thats all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a simple solution:

```
$found = preg_match('/gallery=[0-9]+/', $html, $match);
$gallery_id = (int)substr($match[0], strlen("gallery="));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parse_url` function in order to get the query string value. Check the [`parse_url` function manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

For example:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/path?arg=value#anchor';   
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer as more detail was provided.

The xQuery path you want to use is (this is based on the html you provided, ie the input nodes are at the root of the document)

```
/input[@name='_wp_http_referer']/@value
```

This will allow you to extract the value from the input field. After you have done that you can use a regular expression to extract, so building on your sample above

```
$html = <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="12345678" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="someurl/?album=1&amp;gallery=15" />";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $dom);
$referer = $xpath->evaluate("/input[@name='_wp_http_referer']/@value"); 

if(!empty($referer))
{
    $doesMatch= preg_match("/gallery\=(\d+)/", $referer, $matches);
    if($doesMatch > 0)
    {
        $gallery=$matches[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: He isn't posting the data, but processing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="12345678" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="someurl/?album=1&amp;gallery=15" />";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $dom);
$galleryid = $xpath->query('//input')->item(1); //get second input
parse_str($galleryid);
echo $gallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple enough string manipulation which can be performed using XPath 1.0.

```
substring-after(//input/@value, 'gallery=')
```

Yet using `parse_url` like proposed in another answer is probably the more elegant solution, but this depends on your use case. Using XPath string manipulation could be reasonable for example if you need to use this as intermediate result for filtering in a predicate.